# Iclude php file in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

How do I include a php page in a wordpress post?

I know how to include in pages, using /* Template Name: templatename */ and select a value from dropdown attributes. I don't know how to achieve this in a post, can you help?

i have file ex.php and i want to display the contents of the file in post article.

Answer (score 0):

The template file for single posts is `single.php`

Depending on your theme you might have to create it
 (for example copy index.php and name it accordingly)

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Single_Post_.28single.php.29